# Ocultar/Mostrar iconos con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo una página web, y quiero que al presionar un botón, dos elementos que están al lado de éste se oculten para mostrar otro elemento en su lugar, pero no me funciona, ¿qué es lo que tengo mal?

El elemento a con el id lupita es el que al presionar debe ocultar los otros dos elementos `a`:

```js
document.getElementById('lupita').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('i will');
  document.getElementsByClassName('iconos').style.display = 'none';

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/fontawesome.min.css" />

<a id="lupita" class=" disabledd grande" href="#"><i class="icon fas fa-search"></i>
<a class = "iconos" href = "#"><i class=" icon fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a class="iconos" href="#"><i class="icon fas fa-address-book"></i></a>
```

Escribí el alert para verificar que no era problema del evento del click y el alert sí  funciona pero la siguiente línea de `display` none no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como estas asignando un evento **click** a un elemento `<a>` te recomiendo primero que todo hacer un `event.preventDefault()` para anular el comportamiento por defecto que trae dicho elemento (el cual es redirigir el sitio a otra ventana o página).

Ahora el `document.getElementsByClassName()` te trae todos los elementos que tengan la clase especificada por lo cual en **JavaScript Nativo** tendrás que recorrer estos elementos y en cada iteración aplicar el estilo deseado al elemento específico, así:

```js
document.getElementById('lupita').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var iconos = document.getElementsByClassName('iconos');
    
    // Forma larga 
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(iconos, function(elemento){
        elemento.style.display = 'none';
    });
    
    // Forma corta usando ES6
    Array.from(iconos).forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

```html
<a id="lupita" class="disabledd grande" href = "#">Ancla</a>

<a class="iconos" href="#">Icono 1</a>
<a class="iconos" href="#">Icono 2</a>
```

De igual forma te dejo el ejemplo de como sería usando la librería **jQuery** de **JavaScript** la cual facilita mucho el desarrollo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lupita").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(".iconos").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="lupita" class="disabledd grande" href = "#">Ancla</a>

<a class="iconos" href="#">Icono 1</a>
<a class="iconos" href="#">Icono 2</a>
```

Como puedes ver en el último ejemplo el código es mucho mas corto y fácil de entender y mantener, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estas obteniendo un arreglo de los objetos con la clase iconos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="lupita" class=" disabledd grande" href="#"><i class=" fa fa-search"></i>
        <a class="iconos" href="#"><i class=" fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a class="iconos" href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-book"></i></a>

</body>
<script>
//primero obtenies los objetos con la clase y luego los recorres para ocultar cada uno        
document.getElementById('lupita').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.iconos'),
            i = 0,
            l = myClasses.length;

        for (i; i < l; i++) {
            myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
        }


    })
</script>


</html>
```

nota: Use otra libreria de icono que ya tenia en en mi editor tu solo usa los que ya tenias

Answer (score 0):

El tema es debes diferenciar los elementos que son inline (ej, el `<a>`, `<span>`) que no genera bloques, con los elementos de bloques como los `<div>`.
Esta diferencia hacer que si quieres ocultar un elemento inline debes ocultar el bloque que los contiene o bien convertir estos en elementos de bloque utilizando CSS `display:block`.

Primero pondría los iconos en un `<div>`

```
<div>
  <a  id = "lupita" class = " disabledd grande" href = "#"><i class="icon fas fa-search"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="icon" class="showIcons">
  <a class = "iconos" href = "#"><i class=" icon fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a class = "iconos" href = "#"><i class="icon fas fa-address-book"></i></a>
</div>
```

Agregamos los css

```
.showIcons {
  display: block;
}

.hideIcons {
  display: none;
}
```

Y utilizamos Jquery para que sea mas sencillo

```
// find elements
var lupita = $("#lupita");
var iconBlock = $("#icon");

// handle click and add class
lupita.on("click", function() {
  iconBlock
    .toggleClass("showIcons")
    .toggleClass("hideIcons");
})
```

Acá hice un fiddle para que lo veas funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/06hfctgL/1/

Comment: Andres, un elemento que por default es inline se puede ocultar sin problemas usando la propiedad display, no tiene que ser block ni tampoco tiene que estar contenido dentro de un padre, saludos